# Time independent vs. time dependent lagrange multiplier

Tags: optimization, calculus-of-variations, lagrange-multiplier, euler-lagrange-equation

What are the differences between these two in applications?
For example:
$$max\sum_{t=0}^{\infty} \beta^t u(c_t)$$$$s.t.f(c_t,c_{t+1},x_t,x_{t+1})=0$$
What are the differences between:
$$L=\sum_{t=0}^{\infty} \beta^t u(c_t)+\lambda_tf(c_t,c_{t+1},x_t,x_{t+1})$$
and
$$L=\sum_{t=0}^{\infty} \beta^t u(c_t)+\lambda f(c_t,c_{t+1},x_t,x_{t+1})$$
My prof says it represents the same problem... But in some cases I do find it gives different results...